# Yii running on PHP 5.5

Tags: php, yii, compatibility, php-5.5

I have not found any relevant info about if the Yii Framework (1.1.x) is compatible with PHP 5.5 without changes. Any idea about this?
I have an application running on PHP 5.3 and need to upgrade to 5.5, but I have to know in front, as my customer will not pay the time I "try" installing it..
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the download page:

`Requirement: PHP 5.1.0 or above`

Yes, it works with `PHP 5.5`, but more important, if you are planning upgrading your Yii version, you should take a look to [Upgrade Guide](http://static.yiiframework.com/files/UPGRADE-1.1.15.txt)

Comment: Thanks! I do no plan to upgrage my Yii version, it is up to date, I just need to upgrade the PHP version on the server

Comment: but this is the MINIMAL requirement, but it does not explicitly state, that there are no deprecated issues with 5.5

Comment: in the meantime I have upgraded my PHP to 7.0.x and it is working fine :)